# How to size SQL Server VM so that it is comparable to bare metal primary SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, azure-vm

Are there any guidelines for sizing a new Windows SQL Server VM in Azure so that it matches performance of the on-prem / bare-metal primary SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the online Microsoft guide about it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/performance-guidelines-best-practices

interesting to point out:

> If you are creating a new SQL Server on Azure VM and are not migrating
> a current source system, create your new SQL Server VM based on your
> vendor requirements. The vendor requirements for a SQL Server VM are
> the same as what you would deploy on-premises.

Not to mouch after all. Said that I believe you have to do some test, but how?

You have to capture the on premise workload and reply it to an the azure vm and check the results.

A goo tool for doing it is this:

https://github.com/spaghettidba/WorkloadTools/wiki

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go the other way around, choose an Azure plan and match that on your on-premises.

1. Go first on Azure and choose your right setup: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/series/

   - CPU: pay attention to the brand (Intel/AMD), the GHz and the number of cores
   - RAM: Number of Gb
   - HD: there are two ranges of SSD
   - GPU: a few options
2. Now recreate that environment on your on-premises: based on what you can have on Azure try to have the same on your office.